# How do I prevent vim from hiding symbols in markdown and json?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

This drives me crazy, I do

```
:set ft=text
```

To see something, otherwise all the links disappear in markdown and quotes in JSON.

How do disable this once and for all?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean? Also, while editing a markdown file, do `:redir > foo`, `:hi` (browse through all the highlight groups pressing space), `:redir end`, and add the contents of the newly created `foo` file here.

Comment: "# \_this\_ \*\*that\*\*" will display as "# this that"

Comment: @masukomi, use the shorthand version `:set cole=0` to turn off concealing of markdown bold `**` and italic `*` marks as well as the replacement of `# Title` to `§ Title` (more in nobe4's answer below).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

(guessing here, please provide a screenshot/more information)

You may want to change your `conceallevel` setup:

```
:h 'conceallevel'
'conceallevel' 'cole'       *'conceallevel'* *'cole'*
            number (default 0)
            local to window
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the |+conceal|
            feature}
    Determine how text with the "conceal" syntax attribute |:syn-conceal|
    is shown:

    Value       Effect ~
    0       Text is shown normally
    1       Each block of concealed text is replaced with one
            character.  If the syntax item does not have a custom
            replacement character defined (see |:syn-cchar|) the
            character defined in 'listchars' is used (default is a
            space).
            It is highlighted with the "Conceal" highlight group.
    2       Concealed text is completely hidden unless it has a
            custom replacement character defined (see
            |:syn-cchar|).
    3       Concealed text is completely hidden.
```

Comment: Oh yeah, just set it to zero in config and that seems to fix it. Interesting that it is 0 by default, I guess some plugins change the settings.

Comment: It seems that `conceallevel` is reset every time you open a file. Any way to make it always stick with 0?

Comment: In your vimrc? `set conceallevel=2`

Comment: To answer my own question and maybe help anyone facing the same issue: I have the [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) plugin installed, which forces `conceallevel` to be set to 2 by default for every file. This can be disabled with: `let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0`

Comment: `g:indentLine_setConceal = 0` essentially makes it so the indentline plugin no longer works. I found `let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['json']` worked better for me.

Comment: thanks. it works

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the 'indentLine' plugin or other plugins that can change 'conceal' features in vim. It is because these plugin enables the Vim 'conceal' feature which automatically hides stretches of text based on syntax highlighting. This setting will apply to all syntax items.
Specifically, in 'indentLine' plugin, it will overwrite "concealcursor" and "conceallevel" to:

```
let g:indentLine_concealcursor = 'inc'
let g:indentLine_conceallevel = 2
```

So, I change it to the following value in my .vimrc file:

```
let g:indentLine_setConceal = 2
" default ''.
" n for Normal mode
" v for Visual mode
" i for Insert mode
" c for Command line editing, for 'incsearch'
let g:indentLine_concealcursor = ""
```

Another option is to `let g:indentLine_concealcursor = "nc"` which makes the hidden texts surrounding around your cursor only show in 'insert' mode and 'visual' mode.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) and want to *keep* it working but want to prevent Vim from hiding things in JSON and Markdown, the solution is to ask your syntax highlighting to not use the conceal feature.

For the JSON and Markdown syntax files included in [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot), that's accomplished using the following three lines:

```
let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0
let g:vim_markdown_conceal = 0
let g:vim_markdown_conceal_code_blocks = 0
```

Comment: @thiagowfx I've rejected your edit; if you want an answer to incorporate additional code, consider leaving a comment with a request, or adding your own answer.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Actually, at the time I wrote that, I was under the impression that `g:vim_markdown_conceal` functioned as a master kill switch, so the edit brought it more in line with my intent.

Comment: fair enough—but reviewers can’t know that if there’s no indication :) that’s why commenting is so effective to help improve answers when it comes to code, IMO

Comment: \*chuckle* "fair enough" is *my* response. Now how am I supposed to acknowledge your point without sounding repetitive? Either way, I'll admit that "ask your syntax highlighting to not use the conceal feature" *is* a bit too subtle a cue that I'd intended it to disable *all* use.

Comment: >  so the edit brought it more in line with my intent | 
Indeed that's what I thought.

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin, put in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vim_markdown_conceal = 0
let g:vim_markdown_conceal_code_blocks = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problems ([issues/512](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/issues/512)) when using [plasticboy/vim-markdowd](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin.

I have removed all other plugins and grep conceal in .vim folder, it's confirmed there is no **conceal** related settings except in .vim/bundle/vim-markdowd.

The answer from @Karlo Guidoni Martins seems didn't work for me.
I add the 2 lines into the start and into the end of vimrc file.

Comment: Are you answering or stating that no solution worked (ie you have a question)?

Answer (score 1):

To disable conceal for JSON and Markdown without disabling indentLine plugin, add these lines to your .vimrc :

```
let g:vim_json_conceal=0
let g:markdown_syntax_conceal=0
```

Source :
[official indentLine documentation](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine)

Comment: The information in your answer appears to be covered by existing answers which have been around for a while. Repeating someone else's answer—even if you came up with it independently!—isn't really a goal of the site.

Comment: Nobody proposed my answer. Official doc recommends **exactly** these two lines. I tried other answers...it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, apologies; I misread an answer which had almost the same two variables :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt Greer for sharing his solution for disabling the indentLine plugin for a (list of) file types.

Another option is to enable the indentLine plugin only for specific file types. Add the following line to your vimrc to enable the indentLine plugin for yaml only. It will then be disabled for any other file type.(e.g markdown ...).

```
let g:indentLine_fileType = ['yaml']
```

Comment: Welcome to vi.se :) I could be wrong but I think this indexLine plugin you are talking about is not built-in or shipped with vim, right? If it's an external plugin it would be useful to add a link to its repository. *EDIT* Actually I just saw that other answers are about this plugin, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different and why it would be better (or not) to use it.

Comment: hi @statox - thanks for the notice. Matt Greer posted the solution to disable filetypes for the indentLine plugin. I think it's more convenient to only enable the indentLine plugin for the filetypes where it's actually needed for (e.g yaml or python)  - so it can not interfere with any other file type.(e.g markdown ...). I should have mentioned that in first place.

Comment: That's definitely worth mentioning in your answer. You can use the [edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/31059/edit) button to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to be because of indentLine plugin builtin conceallevel , and simply altering the conceallevel back to 0 -via the default conceallevel option or from the plugin itself- would make the plugin incapable of showing the indentation indicators .

The optimal option for me right now is adding the `elzr/vim-json` plugin with `let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0` option derived from [this answer](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine/issues/140#issuecomment-173867054)

Answer (score -1):

I also met the same problem and it was related to `conceallevel`.

Fortunately, bellowing two lines solve my problem.

```
let g:vim_markdown_conceal = 0
let g:vim_markdown_conceal_code_blocks = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I didn't downvote, so I can't say for sure, but I suspect the downvote is because the information in your answer is covered by existing answers which have been around for a while. Repeating someone else's answer—even if you came up with it independently!—isn't really a goal of the site.