# JSON quotes not hiding and I *want* them to

Tags: vimrc, conceal, filetype-json

## TL;DR

### What I Want:

JSON files to hide their double quotes (`"`) *until* I enter insert mode on a line, in which event the quotes reappear. I had this behavior on another machine, but I cannot replicate it on a new install of Arch (which I'm sure is not relevant, but context)

### What's happening:

Not that:

[image: a screenshot of what I see when I open a JSON file]

I see quotes.

---

I have the opposite complaint to [this person](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/how-do-i-prevent-vim-from-hiding-symbols-in-markdown-and-json) in that I *want* quotes to disappear and they won't.

I do not have `indentLine` installed. I do have [`vim-polyglot`](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) installed, which, as I understand it, includes [`vim-json`](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json).

However, when I open a `.json` file, I can see quotes, still.

I tried out `indentLine`, but the quotes *did not come back when the cursor was on their line,* so I uninstalled it. Playing with conceallevel didn't help me.

My rc (updated according to @statox's suggestion):

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
      silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
          \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
        autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
    endif

" :h filetype said just this was OK
filetype on
syntax enable

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Declare the list of plugins.
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'reedes/vim-colors-pencil'
call plug#end()

syntax on

colorscheme pencil
set background=dark
```

My `vim --version` reports the following:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled May 23 2020 22:02:57)
Included patches: 1-814
Compiled by Arch Linux
```

I bet it's something really dumb, but I miss the clean look of quoteless JSON.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Don't you need something like `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc before the call to `plug#being`? Otherwise the filetype detection is not enabled and the ftplugin which creates the concealing is not loaded, right?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you!!!

Comment: @statox God knows. Let me give that a whirl.

Comment: @statox No dice, my dude :(

Comment: What does `:set ft?` return? Does `:let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal` say it's set to 1? Does `:scriptnames` list both `ftplugin/json.vim` and `syntax/json.vim` from polyglot?

Comment: `:set ft` - `filetype=json`
`:let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal` - `g:vim_json_syntax_conceal #0` 

`vim-polyglot/syntax/json.vim` and `vim-polyglot/ftplugin/json.vim` are both listed.

I'll go add let g:vim_json... to my rc, one moment please @filbranden

Comment: @hoobydooby It should default to 1... Try `:verbose let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal` to see where the zero is coming from?

Comment: If you want a workaround add `:let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 1` to your vimrc, but I'd rather prefer to understand why you're not getting the expected behavior...

Comment: Also make sure your plug-ins are up to date... Run `:PlugUpdate` and `:PlugUpgrade` to update them if needed

Comment: `:verbose let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal` returns the same `g:vim_json_syntax_conceal #0 ` :thinking:

Comment: my plugins are 100% up-to-date

Comment: the workaround works!!! thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue is due to you simply having:

```
filetype on
```

While what you usually want is:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

The former simply enables filetype *detection*, while the latter enables filetype plug-ins and indent plug-ins.

The filetype plug-in for json (`ftplugin/json.vim`) is the one which defaults `g:vim_json_syntax_conceal` to 1. You should have that plug-in run early in Vim initialization to have conceal set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I add this to the end of my rc, it works:

```
let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 1
```

Thank you @fibranden!

Comment: The reason this happens is that vim-polyglot [actively disables](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/db7bb8ba22f5798bf3abe9f786bc6e6d002725f8/autoload/polyglot/init.vim#L93) vim-json's conceal feature if you don't turn it on manually. I do not know why the maintainer made this decision, but that's what it is.